# Como recibir datos de un Fragment B a un Fragment A en Android usando Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, livedata

Después de mucha investigación y lectura ví que no hay mucha documentación en cuanto como retornar datos de un Fragment B a un Fragment A usando navigation.
Supongamos que tengamos una opción de modificación de datos de usuario y el mismo de un Fragment A nos lleve al Fragment B pero cuando retornemos al Fragment A queremos ver los datos recientemente actualizados en el Fragment A. Anteriormente se resolvia eso en el método onActivityResult pero cuando usamos navigation Component la cosa Cambia ya que segun la documentacion que nos provee Android nos dice que onActivityResult no se llama usando navigation components. 
Para resolver eso entonces usamos el sgte código en el Fragment B en el evento o metodo que querramos.

```
   class FragmentB:Fragment(){  
       private lateinit var navController: NavController

       onviewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
          
          navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)        
          
          val result = Bundle().apply {
           putString("TAG","DATO")
          }
          button.OnClickListener{
             navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", result)
             
             //Con esto regresamos al fragment Anterior usando navigation
             navController.popBackStack()
          }
       }
    }
```

y para recibir los datos del FragmentB en el fragment A usamos el sgte cogigo:

```
   class FragmentA:Fragment(){  
       private lateinit var navController: NavController

       onviewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
          
          navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)        
          
          //consultamos los datos obtenidos del fragmentB
          navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Bundle>("key")?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer
        {
           val bundle:Bundle = it
           Log.e("trajo algo", bundle.getString("TAG", ""))
        })
       }
    }
```

Como se puede observar por medio del "key" el busca que dato fue lo que se almaceno por medio dek Key... y en el metodo getLiveData le decimos que tipo de dato es lo que esperamos recibir, en mi caso espero recibir una clase Bundle pero ustedes pueden retornar el tipo de dato que deseen.Espero esto les sirva, yo me tarde un dia en buscar la solución a mi problema. Pueden leer en la documentación de android sobre LiveData: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata